# Split and reverse a string, and keep numbers, letters, special characters... together

Tags: string, flutter, dart, reverse

I want to Split and reverse an Arabic string, and keep numbers, letters, special characters.. together (pretending all Arabic letters are isolated).

Example of my code :

```
void main() {
  var sentence = ' Suit إجمالى المنتجات 359.00 Dhs ,مشاركة';
  var originalList = sentence.split('').toList();
  print(originalList.reversed.toList().join());
}
```

And here is the output from this code:

```
ةكراشم, shD 00.953 تاجتنملا ىلامجإ tiuS stropS dlihC
```

Arabic letters are good but I want to avoid reversing any character except the list of the Arabic letters.

here:

```
List<String> arabicLetters = [
  'ا',
  'ب',
  'ت',
  'ث',
  'ج',
  'ح',
  'خ',
  'د',
  'ذ',
  'ر',
  'ز',
  'س',
  'ش',
  'ص',
  'ض',
  'ط',
  'ظ',
  'ع',
  'غ',
  'ف',
  'ق',
  'ك',
  'ل',
  'م',
  'ن',
  'ه',
  'و',
  'ي',
  'أ',
  'إ',
  'ؤ',
  'ئ',
  'آ',
  'ى',
  'ة',
];
```

Comment: it reverses the numbers, you need to modify the regexp: `String reverse(String s) {
  if (s.isEmpty) {
    return '';
  }
  return s.toList().reversed.reduce((value, element) => value += element);
}

var replaceSet = RegExp('[0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0]+');
var foo = 'Ut occaecat 1235 culpa 3479 incididunt 2478 culpa.';
var replaced = foo.splitMapJoin(replaceSet, onMatch: (m) => reverse(m.group(0)));
print(foo);
print(replaced);`

Comment: there is an error : the method 'toList' is undefined for the type String. how can fix it?

Comment: ah, I had some extension, you need to implement `reverse` function as you did in your question then, using `split('')`

Comment: I mean `return s.split('').toList() ...` etc

Comment: Thank you very much you, i am in the right path now, is there any way i can point to my arabic letters inside regexp? actually i have two lists i want to point to instead of tapping all the elements

Comment: it is five lists, not two every arabic letter has 4 forms: isloated, initial, medial, final plus vowels

Comment: @pskink you helped me a lot thank so much, if you have any suggestion about my previous comment, i will be grateful

Comment: sorry I have no idea how Arabic language works

Comment: @pskink sorry may be i didnt explain my question very well, returning to the example you provided me, if i extract all the numbers from the RegExp(XXXXXX) and i put them in al List or 2 List just for exemple, how can i represant them in the RegExp([here])? i am sorry

Comment: `var list = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  print(list.join('|'));` - is it what you want?

Comment: No, I am sorry, lol, i want simply instead of 
´´´
RegExp('[0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0]+');
//
var list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
RegExp('[point to the list here]+');
´´´

Comment: sorry then, i have no idea what you really want

Comment: It is only to avoid repetition, 5 lists inside RegExp parentheses it will be somehow inappropriate, we can see it is code refection, sorry again, anyway thank you very much you saved my time @pskink.

Comment: @pskink Thank you, i made it, i just mixed all my lists, and i passed it like this: 
var allLists = [ ...listTachkilAtTheEnd, ...initial, ...medial, ...isolated, ...finalList ]; RegExp('$allLists+'); thank you so much you saved my life

Comment: sure, your welcome, you can post a self answer then...

Comment: @pskink one last question please, the final output looks as I wanted but the words (i am not talking about letters or special characters) looks reversed  like this: 'day beautiful a is It' , any idea how i can reverse the whole list of (words) in the text to look like: 'It is a beautiful day' ? thanks in advance

Comment: 'foo bar spam'.split(' ').reverse

Comment: @pskink when i run :
print('foo bar spam'.split(' ').reversed.join()) the output is 'spambarfoo' without spaces between words.

Comment: check the documentation, for example for `join` method

Comment: @pskink i did it Thank You:   
var fooList = 'foo bar spam'.split(' ').reversed.toList().join(' ');

Comment: you don't need toList()

Comment: @pskink yes i don't need toList(), all i did that matters is adding a pattern to .join() function, in this case a space ' '